# how do i write down the matrix A and the right-hand side vector b corresponding to the system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, interpolation

I need how to get to the answer for this question. I made this in a study group, but we didn't write down how we got to the answer and now i've been stuck on it for a long time. i cant seem to make any sense of it.

we have 8 unknown coefficients to determine. We shall see that the $x$-coefficients can be determined independently from $y$-coefficients, and that the procedure is exactly the same for both sets of coefficients. We will therefore focus on the $x$-coefficients.
The equations that $x(t)$ has to satisfy are:
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
x(0) & =x_1, \\
x^{\prime}(0) & =3\left(x_2-x_1\right), \\
x^{\prime}(1) & =3\left(x_4-x_3\right), \\
x(1) & =x_4 .
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Write down the matrix $A$ and the right-hand side vector $b$ correspoinding to the system of equations (19). Solve the system (19) using Gaussian elimination to find the explicit formulas for $\left(p_x, q_x, r_x, s_x\right) \in$ $\mathbb{R}^4$ in terms of the data $\left(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\right) \in \mathbb{R}^4$.
Clearly the formulas for $\left(p_y, q_y, r_y, s_y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ are analogous.
$$

**This is the answer we got**:

$$
\begin{gathered}
x(0)=p_x=x_1 \\
x^{\prime}(0)=q_x=3\left(x_2-x_1\right) \\
x^{\prime}(1)=q_x+2 r_x+3 s_x=3\left(x_4-x_3\right) \\
x(1)=p_x+q_x+r_x+s_x=x_4
\end{gathered}
$$
This is the part that makes me confused, how does x'(0) correspond $=q_x=3\left(x_2-x_1\right) $ and so on.

$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \begin{gathered}
x_1 \\
3\left(x_2-x_1\right) \\
-6 x_2+3 x_1+3 x_3 \\
x_4-3 x_3+3 x_2-x_1
\end{gathered}
$$